# Grails javascript render from controller to gsp

Tags: javascript, grails

I am trying to render some Javascript from my controller to my GSP like this:

```
render text: """<script type="text/javascript">
                                            alert("Row number: " + rowNumber); 
                                        </script>""",
                               contentType: 'js'
```

where "rowNumber" is a variable in my Controller and I want the value of it to appear in the alert box. I can't seem to figure out the syntax and need a little help. Presently I get this error in the browser:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: rowNumber is not defined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want something like this:

```
render text: """<script type="text/javascript">
                    alert("Row number: " + ${rowNumber}); 
                </script>""",
       contentType: 'js'
```

That will cause the value of `rowNumber` in your controller to be substituted into the string before the string is rendered.

**EDIT:**

(another option)

You could do away with the concatenation altogether with something like this:

```
render text: """<script type="text/javascript">
                    alert("Row number: ${rowNumber}"); 
                </script>""",
       contentType: 'js'
```

Comment: The way you had it, the literal `alert("Row number: " + rowNumber);` is what would be rendered instead of something like `alert("Row number: " + 42);`.

Comment: All of that assumes there is a variable named `rowNumber` in scope where you are calling `render` in your controller there.

Comment: Note that you could also put the JavaScript into a template and render that from the controller rather than having to triple-quote it inline. Then you would pass `rowNumber` into the template, e.g., `render template: 'rowNumberJS', model: [rowNumber: rowNumber]`